# redirect all non-www to www, all http to https, and exclude subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect

example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
and
`http://example.come to https://www.example.com`

HOWEVER, if a user types in

`admin.example.com, http://admin.example.com or https://admin.example.com`
it should NOT redirect to `www.admin.example.com`

What .htaccess can I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Regex pattern `(?:www\.)?([^.]+\.[^.]+)` will match `example.com` or `www.example.com` but not `admin.example.com`

Comment: sir, instead of example\.com we have to use our domina name . right?

Comment: @user9437856: Please check updated answer. I have removed reference to `example.com` from my rule.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for the answer. I have a main domain HTTPS and it's redirecting on www. Now my subdomain is not redirecting on HTTPS and www. This issue is solved. Now I have a doubt, If I buy the HTTPS and www for the subdomain then do I need to change the above code?

Comment: Yes once you do that just comment out 3rd `RewriteCond` above.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try this once I get the www server for the subdomain. Upvote from my side